# Laravel Eloquent - Return unique values only and ignore all that appear more than once

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 database tables.

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Users          |     Matches      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     user_id         |     match_id     |
|---------------------|------------------|
                      |     user_1       |
                      |------------------|
                      |     user_2       |
                      |------------------|
```

with `user_1` and `user_2` being `user_id`s.

I am now trying to retrieve all matches with unique values only. As soon as a user ID is used twice, I don't want to retrieve ANY matches containing the id.

Example:

MATCHES (match_id, user_1, user_2):

`1, 1, 2`
`2, 1, 3`
`3, 4, 5`
`4, 6, 7`
`5, 7, 8`

The query should return `3, 4, 5` ONLY, because it's the only match containing only unique user_ids.

How should I go about this? I've been trying an approach using `->distinct()` but that doesn't work since it only removes duplicates but I want to kick other entries containing the values as well.

Comment: Only `user_1` distinctness or `user_2` too ?

Comment: @Ersoy Both have to be distinct.

Comment: @SadHippo123 I undeleted my answer, after fixing my solution. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple and crude, not a query based solution, but will get you what you want.

```
public function strictlyUniqueMatches()
{
    $matches = Matches::distinct()->get();
    
    $present = [];

    foreach ($matches as $idx => $match) {
        if (!isset($present[$match->user_1])) {
            $present[$match->user_1] = 0;
        }

        if (!isset($present[$match->user_2])) {
            $present[$match->user_2] = 0;
        }

        $present[$match->user_1]++;
        $present[$match->user_2]++;
    }

    return $matches->filter(function ($match) use ($present) {
        if ($present[$match->user_1] > 1) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($present[$match->user_2] > 1) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    });
}
```

Comment: I was hoping I could solve this somehow directly in the query but I will use this for now and update, if I happen to find an alternative solution. Thank you!

Comment: Your solution throws an `Undefined offset:` error in the first `foreach` but using `isset` to check if `$present[$match->user_1]` and `$present[$match->user_2]` are available and setting to 1 otherwise fixes the problem. Thank you, again! It might not be exactly what I was looking for but definitely works.

Comment: @SadHippo123 Thanks!I will update my answer. If you are looking for an SQL solution, the query will be quite inefficient in comparison I believe. But I am not an SQL wizard.